# Split string with [] brackets

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a string `'attributes.inquiry_result[{name: tran type}]'`, want split it in a way it returns array `['attributes', 'inquiry_result', '{name: tran type}']`.

I tried with `'attributes.inquiry_result[{name: tran type}]'.split(/\[([^[\]]*)\]/);`, but it do not split by dot, returns `['attributes.inquiry_result', '{name: tran type}']`

Tried adding logic for dot, but it resulting in something else.

Comment: Could you provide your current code?

Comment: Hi @Yannick, this is current code. but want to split by dot as well along with brackets. 'attributes.inquiry_result[{name: tran type}]'.split(/\[([^[\]]*)\]/);

Comment: `"attributes.inquiry_result[{name: tran type}]".replace("]", "").split(/\.|\[/g)` should work for the exact given input.

Comment: Thanks. It worked as expected. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the split function with Regex. Filter is being used to remove the last empty value, since your string ends with the character "]"

```js
const string = 'attributes.inquiry_result[{name: tran type}]';

const result = string.split(/\.|]|\[/).filter(item => item);

console.log(result);
```